# Recursively through heavy nested JSON

Tags: c#, recursion, json.net

So I am a bit stucked right now.

I want to go through a nested JObject with recursion

The json looks sth like that

```
"Name":"Bob",
"Place":{
    "Name":"New York",
    "Address":{
        "Name":"Elmstreet",
        "Number":13
    },
    "Country":"Calif"
}`
```

I want to store it in my Poco which looks sth like that

```
public class Variance
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public IList<Variance> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Therefore I need a List to store all variances,

```
List<Variance> listOfAll = new List<Variance>();
```

What I've tried but it doesnt really work for me

```
Variance Recursively(List<JToken> jToken)
    {
        
        foreach (var token in jToken)
        {

            Variance variance = new Variance();
            variance.PropertyName = token.Path;
            if (token.Children().ToList().Count > 1)
                variance.Children.Add(Recursively(token.Children().ToList()));
            listOfAll.Add(variance);
            return variance;

        }
        return null;
    }
```

What I really want is that the list contain all variances and these variances should contain the children as a List

Currently the listofAll only contains 1 Variance (name) instead of two (name and place) place then should contain name address and Country. Then address should contain Name and number.

Comment: Please give us a more representative JSON document to work with.

Comment: Also, what doesn't work?

Comment: The list (listofAll) contains only one element and this element has no children which is true, but it schould contain 2 elements name and place and the variance place should contain children like name and city.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use just *Propeties*, like the following code :

1 - Change Children type to `List` for using `.AddRange()` in `Recursively` method :

```
public class Variance
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public List<Variance> Children { get; set; }
}
```

2 - Recursively method takes collection of properties and checks if the nested json is an object or not :

```
static List<Variance> Recursively(IEnumerable<JProperty> jProperties)
{
    List<Variance> listOfAll = new List<Variance>();

    foreach (JProperty jProperty in jProperties)
    {
        Variance variance = new Variance
        {
            PropertyName = jProperty.Path
        };

        if (jProperty.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            variance.Children = new List<Variance>();
            List<Variance> recuList = Recursively(((JObject)jProperty.Value).Properties());
            variance.Children.AddRange(recuList);
        }

        listOfAll.Add(variance);
    }

    return listOfAll;
}
```

3 - Call `Recursively` like :

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
List<Variance> result = Recursively(jObject.Properties());
```

Note that, if you have nested json like an array, you might want to tweak the method.

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This solution specifically returns a `List<string>` of values that recursively match provided property name.

You can tailor the `JTokenType` to your needs for other value types.

Credit to [Mohammed Sajid's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745795/mohammed-sajid) answer for providing a starting point.

**Usage:**

```cs
var res = GetStringValuesRecursive(myJObj, "failure_reason");
```

**Function:**

```cs
public static List<string> GetStringValuesRecursive(JObject jo, string propName)
{     
  return RecurseForString(jo.Properties(), propName);    
}
```

**Helper**

```cs
private static List<string> RecurseForString(
  IEnumerable<JProperty> jProperties, 
  string propName, 
  List<string> res = null)
{
  res ??= new List<string>();

  foreach (var jProp in jProperties)
  {
    switch(jProp.Value.Type)
    {
      case JTokenType.String:
        if (propName == jProp.Name)
          res.Add((string)jProp.Value);
        break;
      case JTokenType.Object:
        RecurseForString(((JObject)jProp.Value).Properties(), propName, res);
        break;
      case JTokenType.Array:
        foreach (var ja in (JArray)jProp.Value)
        {
          switch(ja.Type)
          {
            case JTokenType.String:
              //  This is an array of strings
              if (propName == jProp.Name)
                res.Add(ja.Value<string>());
              break;
            case JTokenType.Object:
              RecurseForString(((JObject)ja).Properties(), propName, res);
              break;
            case JTokenType.Array:     
              // If need to Impl.. Consider while child.Type == Array, get next child.
              throw new NotImplementedException("Array of Array not implemented in RecurseForString.");
          }              
        }
        break;
    }
  }

  return res;
}
```