# Unable to find diff of two json properly in c#. Also getting error if there are 3 or more changes

Tags: c#, json

I have two json string namely left(original json) and right(edited json). I want to find the difference between left and right and create a new json with only the changes and specific key "ID" AND "TYPE" . I tried using "[JsonDiffPatchDotNet](https://github.com/wbish/jsondiffpatch.net)" and "[JsonDiffer](https://github.com/aminm-net/JsonDiffer.Netstandard)" packages in c# but no luck could someone help me out with this. Here is the code i have tried !

> PACKAGES

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using JsonDiffPatchDotNet;
    using JsonDiffer;
```

> CODE MINIFY

```
   public static string Minify(string json)
        {
            if (json == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(json));
            }

            return Regex.Replace(json, "(\"(?:[^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*\")|\\s+", "$1");
        }
```

> CODE MAIN LOGIC

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
   {


            string Tleft = @"{
                    ""TEST JSON"" : ""JSON"",
                    ""JSON"":{
                                ""ANIMALS"":[
                                    {
                                ""ID"":0,
                                        ""TYPE"":""DOG"",
                                        ""DOG"":{
                                    ""TYPE"":""RETRIEVER"",
                                            ""RETRIEVER"":{
                                        ""NAME"":""LEO"",
                                                ""AGE"":3,
                                                ""YEARS"":[2019 , 2020, 2021],
                                        ""WEIGHTS"": [2,10,13]
                }
                },
                                ""REMARKS"":{
                                    ""ID"":1,
                                    ""STATUS"":""GOOD"",
                                    ""REFERENCE"": {
                                        ""SOURCE"": ""XYZ"",
                                        ""FIT"":  1,
                                        ""BMI"" : 1
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                ""ID"":1,
                                ""TYPE"":""DOG2"",
                                ""DOG2"":{
                                    ""TYPE"":""PUG"",
                                    ""RETRIEVER"":{
                                        ""NAME"":""HUTCH"",
                                        ""AGE"":4,
                                        ""YEARS"":[2019 , 2020, 2021, 2022],
                                        ""WEIGHTS"": [2,3,4,4]
                                    }
                                },
                                ""REMARKS"":{
                                    ""ID"":1,
                                    ""TYPE"" : ""REFERENCE"",
                                    ""STATUS"":""GOOD"",
                                    ""REFERENCE"": {
                                        ""SOURCE"": ""XYZ"",
                                        ""FIT"":  1,
                                        ""BMI"" : 1
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                ""ID"": 2,
                                ""TYPE"": ""DIAGNOSTICS"",
                                ""STATUS"": ""ENABLED""
                            },
                            {
                                ""ID"": 3,
                                ""TYPE"": ""ORGANISATION"",
                                ""ORGANISATION"":{
                                    ""NAME"":""RED CROSS"",
                                    ""YEAR"": 2023
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }";

            string Tright = @"{
                    ""TEST JSON"" : ""JSON"",
                    ""JSON"":{
                                ""ANIMALS"":[
                                    {
                                ""ID"":0,
                                        ""TYPE"":""DOG"",
                                        ""DOG"":{
                                    ""TYPE"":""RETRIEVER"",
                                            ""RETRIEVER"":{
                                        ""NAME"":""LEO"",
                                                ""AGE"":3,
                                                ""YEARS"":[2019 , 2020, 2021],
                                        ""WEIGHTS"": [2,10,13]
                }
                },
                                ""REMARKS"":{
                                    ""ID"":1,
                                    ""STATUS"":""GOOD"",
                                    ""REFERENCE"": {
                                        ""SOURCE"": ""XYZ"",
                                        ""FIT"":  1,
                                        ""BMI"" : 1
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                ""ID"":1,
                                ""TYPE"":""DOG2"",
                                ""DOG2"":{
                                    ""TYPE"":""PUG"",
                                    ""RETRIEVER"":{
                                        ""NAME"":""HUTCH"",
                                        ""AGE"":4,
                                        ""YEARS"":[2019 , 2020, 2021, 2022],
                                        ""WEIGHTS"": [2,3,4,4]
                                    }
                                },
                                ""REMARKS"":{
                                    ""ID"":1,
                                    ""TYPE"" : ""REFERENCE"",
                                    ""STATUS"":""GOOD"",
                                    ""REFERENCE"": {
                                        ""SOURCE"": ""XYZ"",
                                        ""FIT"":  1,
                                        ""BMI"" : 1
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                ""ID"": 2,
                                ""TYPE"": ""DIAGNOSTICS"",
                                ""STATUS"": ""ENABLED ZZZ""
                            },
                            {
                                ""ID"": 3,
                                ""TYPE"": ""ORGANISATION"",
                                ""ORGANISATION"":{
                                    ""NAME"":""RED CROSS ZZZ"",
                                    ""YEAR"": 2023
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }";

            var left = JToken.Parse(Minify(Tleft));
            var right = JToken.Parse(Minify(Tright));
            var jdp = new JsonDiffPatch();

            // difference using JsonDiffPatchDotNet package
            var diff2 = JsonDifferentiator.Differentiate(left, right, OutputMode.Symbol, showOriginalValues: true);


            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("----diff using JsonDiffPatchDotNet----");
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine(diff2);
            Console.WriteLine("***************************************");
            Console.WriteLine("***************************************\n\n");

            if (diff2 != null)
            {
                // removing * charecter from the difference
                var formatedDiff = JToken.Parse(diff2.ToString().Replace("*", ""));
                
                // patching with diff2
                //  Error occurs here if ther are more than 3 changes .
                var Diff2PatchOutput = jdp.Patch(left, formatedDiff).ToString();

                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("---------- CURRENT OUTPUT --------");
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine(Diff2PatchOutput);
                Console.WriteLine("***************************************");
                Console.WriteLine("***************************************\n\n");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Diff failed  or Invalid json inputs left and rigth !");
            }
        }
```

> CURRETN OUPUT

```
--------------------------------------
----diff using JsonDiffPatchDotNet----
--------------------------------------
{
  "*JSON": {
    "*ANIMALS": [
      {
        "*STATUS": "ENABLED ZZZ"
      },
      {
        "*ORGANISATION": {
          "*NAME": "RED CROSS ZZZ"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
***************************************
***************************************


--------------------------------------
---------- CURRENT OUTPUT --------
--------------------------------------
{
  "TEST JSON": "JSON",
  "JSON": {
    "ANIMALS": {
      "ORGANISATION": {
        "NAME": "RED CROSS ZZZ"
      }
    }
  }
}
***************************************
***************************************
```

I'm trying to get the output like shown below. Any help would be really appreciated !

> EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
--------------------------------------
---------- EXPECTED OUTPUT --------
--------------------------------------
{
  "TEST JSON": "JSON",
  "JSON": {
    "ANIMALS": [
      {
        "ID": 2,
        "TYPE": "DIAGNOSTICS",
        "STATUS": "ENABLED ZZZ"
      }
      {
        "ID": 3,
        "TYPE": "ORGANISATION",
        "ORGANISATION": {
          "NAME": "RED CROSS ZZZ"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
***************************************
***************************************
```

The problem is that if the changes are made in the same index of the JSON then they are being recognized but if they are made at 2 different indexes the first is being ignored. Also if there are changes at more than 2 different indexes it raises and error.

> Error :

```
                       System.IO.InvalidDataException
                                 HResult = 0x80131501
                      Message = Invalid patch object
                      Source = JsonDiffPatchDotNet
                      StackTrace:
                              at JsonDiffPatchDotNet.JsonDiffPatch.Patch(JToken left, JToken patch)
                              at JsonDiffPatchDotNet.JsonDiffPatch.ObjectPatch(JObject obj, JObject patch)
                              at JsonDiffPatchDotNet.JsonDiffPatch.Patch(JToken left, JToken patch)
                              at JsonDiffPatchDotNet.JsonDiffPatch.ObjectPatch(JObject obj, JObject patch)
                              at JsonDiffPatchDotNet.JsonDiffPatch.Patch(JToken left, JToken patch)
```

Please feel free to suggest any other approaches to achieve this .

Answer (score 5):

**Updated Answer**

You're almost there - there's one thing you probably missed in my previous answer:

> - Actually, using two different libraries (where only one of them supports patching) gives no value here.

Meaning, you can really just use your `JsonDiffPatch` object, which has built-in patching support. So just re-introduce your `diff1` of your previous question version, remove `diff2`, and that's it.

You'll end up with just those 3 lines ([see full demo here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/J1EVgH)):

```
var jdp = new JsonDiffPatch();
var diff1 = jdp.Diff(left, right);
// ...
var diff1PatchOutput = jdp.Patch(left, diff1).ToString();
```

And if you want to see just the changed items:

```
var diffAnimalsIds = ((JObject)JObject.Parse(diff1.ToString())["JSON"]["ANIMALS"]).Properties().Select(p => p.Name);    
var allAnimals = JObject.Parse(diff1PatchOutput)["JSON"]["ANIMALS"].Cast<JObject>();
var changedAnimals = allAnimals.Where(animal => diffAnimalsIds.Contains(((JValue)animal["ID"]).ToString()));
```

**Previous Answer**

I'll start by saying that running your code ([see full demo here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EofywD)) doesn't output what you mentioned in your question.

For example, the expected output can't actually be constructed by the provided jsons, beacuse `STATUS` and `NAME` are not the ones which have changes, but `TYPE` and `YEAR`. Visually, these are the changes:

[image]

That said, since I think that what got you those errors is mainly code disorganization, here are several points to help you resolve those issues.

[Don't be intimidated by all those bullets, I'm here to help!]

The first code block is wrong for several reasons:

```
// difference using JsonDiffer package 
var diff1 = jdp.Diff(left, right);

// difference using JsonDiffPatchDotNet package
var diff2 = JsonDifferentiator.Differentiate(right, left...)
```

You've got:

- The comments are the other way around (i.e. `jdp.Diff` is the one using the `JsonDiffPatchDotNet` package)
- You're passing the json copies in two opposites ways (i.e. `left, right` and then `right, left`)
- Actually, using two different libraries (where only one of them supports patching) gives no value here.

Then, the next code block actually digs the hole deeper:

```
var diff1PatchOutput = jdp.Patch(right, diff1).ToString();

// removing * charecter from the difference
var formatedDiff = JToken.Parse(diff2.ToString().Replace("*", ""));
            
// patching with diff2
//  Error occurs here if ther are more than 3 changes .
var diff2PatchOutput = jdp.Patch(right, formatedDiff).ToString();
```

Because:

- `right` and `diff` shouldn't really be patched together, because `right`  is already "patched". You probably want `left` to be patched.
- You shouldn't edit `diff2`, e.g. by removing `*`. If you want to know what's changed, construct the differ with something like `JsonDifferentiator.Differentiate(left, right, OutputMode.Detailed, true)`, which will get you detailed object.
- In the last line, as mentioned above, you probably don't want to patch `right`, as it's already "patched".

Comment: Thanks for the identifying the errors/ mistakes i have made a edit fixing them.

Comment: @DeLorean see my respective edits

Comment: @OfriD  i was trying to get only the changed items from patching not the entire json again. so i was do it in the above way. could you suggest a package or a method to achieve the expected output.

Comment: If you only need the changes, then yeah, you can use `JsonDifferentiator`. But what do you need to actually do with the diff (except from printing)? Normally, you would use it for patching - but for that you already have `jdp`, don't you?

Comment: My aim is to find the difference and add  respective "ID", "DIAGNOSTICS" fields from the original json. As show in the expected output. - hope I'm clear

Comment: @DeLorean you can just search for the changed objects. See my edits (demo also updated).

Comment: but in the demo code its printing the whole json instead of json containing only the changes and its respective "Id" and  "Type"  (PS : the DIAGNOSTICS should have been type in my previous comment ).  I would really appreciate if you could provide the code which print the desired output 

Comment: @DeLorean, my bad, the demo wasn't saved. Check it out now, it's the last print.

Comment: Hi @OfirD , its printing other outputs as well where changes were not made . i have added the changes to the json and here is the link to my demo : https://dotnetfiddle.net/4TKsSr so you could see the what I'm saying (example for the changes i made weights are being printed even though there weren't any changes to that).

Comment: @DeLorean `TEST JSON`, `ID` and `TYPE` weren't changed as well. Why should they be included in the output, then? In other words, what's the rule for including properties in the output? Anyway, I guess you may have to to recurse over each of the original json properties, and check against the diff object if the current property was changed - if true, take it, if not - ignore and continue to the next level. [this may be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62594526/3002584) for this purpose.

Comment: could you provide a code using current test jsons. I'm finding it difficult to follow as I'm new to c#. Hope you understand 

Comment: @DeLorean, well, you'll first have to answer the question in the beginning of my previous comment :) but really, you should try it first yourself using the code I linked to, and also try to Google for keywords such as "recursion over json nested properties" and alike.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251933/discussion-between-ofird-and-delorean).